# Formulario integrado en groupBox

Tags: c#, windows-forms

Tengo un formulario principal dividido en dos groupbox,
el primer groupbox es donde se encuentran las pestañas y en cada pestaña una botonera diferente
el segundo groupbox (gbContenedor) esta vacio, y lo que quiero hacer es que cuando se haga click en uno de los botones se muestre un formulario ( frmHijo )"integrado" en ese groupbox, es decir, que frmhijo ocupe el espacio de gbContenedor y siempre crezca/decrezca en funcion del formulario principal.

Gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para que los controles incluídos en un contenedor se adapten al tamaño del padre tienes que hacer uso de dos propiedades de los mismos:

- Dock: Esta propiedad permite que el control se *pegue* a un lateral del control padre. Muy util para, por ejemplo, crear controles apilados en vertical u horizontal.
- Anchor: Esta propiedad permite fijar la distancia entre los extremos del control hijo y los bordes del control padre. En este caso el control puede encontrarse en cualquier posición. Si el padre ve modificado su tamaño, el control hijo intentará mantener la relación fijada mediante esta propiedad modificando su propio tamaño.

En cuanto a lo que comentas sobre añadir un formulario a un control de usuario... no suele ser lo más recomendable. Hasta donde recuerdo para añadir un formulario a un control de usuario es necesario modificar la propiedad `TopLevelProperty` del formulario. Creo que lo más lógico sería sustituir el formulario por un `UserControl`.

Un ejemplo usando un formulario podría ser:

```
Form frm = new ...;
frm.TopLevel = false;
control.Controls.Add(frm);
```

Comment: gracias @eferion, el tema es que no se como hacer para que el formulario hijo sea que su padre es el groupbox, he intentado añadirlo a a gbContenedor.Controls.Add(frmHijo) pero me da error...

Comment: @Urko estaba editando la respuesta mientras la comentabas. Revisa el nuevo contenido a ver si te es de utilidad

Comment: gracias, era lo de topleve lo que me daba error, al quitarle el toplevel ya va bien.